# Tensorflow-text: NotFoundError: _text_similarity_metric_ops.so not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow-text
```

Actually i'm trying to run on Windows 10 (Pro), version 1909.
Attempts to run on **Python 3.8.5, 3.6.13, and 3.7** brought no result - i've got the same error.

Using Jupiter Notebook, conda (4.10.1)

**Version of Tensorflow - 2.1.0**
Downloading version of Tf-text is **"tensorflow_text-2.4.3-cp36"**

Now i'm trying to reinstall conda, switch tensorflow versions
I hope this issue will be fixed soon.

Comment: Try to add a code snippet or steps when you are getting this error, (while installing, running a specific line of code, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So, this problem was solved easy by myself!*

All you have to do is:

1. *Setup conda enviroment, in Anaconda
   Then in Anaconda cmd run conda activate <your_enviroment_name>*
2. `pip install tensorflow==2.4.1`, `pip install tensorflow-text==2.4.1`

Then it should works.
Remember, run on **Python 3.7.10**

Also guys from tensorflow says that you can run it on python 3.6 and 3.8, but be carefully with TF 2.4.1, i saw some info that *Python 3.6 could not run just that current version.*

Best wishes,
Temio

Comment: I'm still having the problem.